# How can I create a list of Strings in R which contains 5-digit numbers (zip codes)

Tags: r, list, zipcode

I want to create a list like this in R:

00000
00001
00002
...
99999

but all of the content needs to be strings, in order not to loose the zeros.

I am aware of how building a list of integers, but somehow fail in creating a list of string.

I assume that it´s a easy piece of code, but struggle with the string issue...

Best,
Alex

Answer (score 4):

Using `seq` with `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%05d", seq(0, 99999))
```

For demo purposes:

```
sprintf("%02d", seq(0, 12))

[1] "00" "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_pad` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(seq(0, 12), 2, pad = "0")
#[1] "00" "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
```